# How to return an array of the total - reduce function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array of movies, I'm trying to use the reduce function and the expected output should be : 420(the total duration of the 3 objects), the output I'm getting right now is like a concatenation of the 3 strings, why is that?

```js
let movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry Potter',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

let newAr = movies.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => 
[ previousValue + currentValue.duration ], []);

console.log('newAr', newAr)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `previousValue` will be the accumulator, the value returned by the prior iteration of the callback - or, the initial value - so it'll be an array. Doing `someArray + someOtherValue` will coerce the array into a string (in other words, doing `.join(',')`) and concatenate it with the expression on the right.

I'd map the movies to their durations instead, then add them up:

```
const totalDuration = movies
  .map(m => m.duration)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Or do it in one step, though it might be a bit harder to parse at a glance if you're unfamiliar with `reduce`.

```
const totalDuration = movies
  .reduce((a, movie) => a + movie.duration, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const movies = [
  {
    'name': 'Jumanji',
    'duration': 120
  },
  {
    'name': 'Harry Potter',
    'duration': 60
  },
  {
    'name': 'Toy Story',
    'duration': 240
  }
];

console.log(movies.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => 
previousValue + currentValue.duration, 0))
```